# ¿Qué errores tiene este código de python?

Tags: python, array

```
import numpy as np
numero=np.array([2,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,4,6,3])
repeticiones={}
for i in range(0,9):
    if numero==repeticiones:
        repeticiones+=1
    else:
        repeticiones=1
    for j in range(repeticiones):
        if repeticiones >=3:
            print(repeticiones)
```

El código tiene que darme el número que se repita más de 3 veces
he utilizado arreglos

Comment: cual es el error donde falla? que devuelve?

Comment: al ejecutarlo me muestra este error The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Puedes usar un diccionario cuyo key sea el numero y el valor sea la cantidad de repeticiones, luego lo ordenas de mayor a menor y devuelves el ultimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que habrás intentado ejecutar ese código antes de preguntar. No funciona, pero es que no llega a ejecutarse porque al poco de arrancar produce el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kk.py", line 5, in <module>
    if numero==repeticiones:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Una de las primeras cosas que debes aprender para ir progresando en esto de la programación, es aprender a entender los mensajes de error. Vale, en este caso el error es bastante críptico (y es que estás usando `numpy`, que es una biblioteca avanzada y seguramente no necesaria para este caso). Pero si ignoramos el misterioso mensaje de error,  justo antes tienes la línea que lo ha producido:

```
if numero == repeticiones:
```

Algo hay mal en esa comparación ¿qué puede ser? Examinemos qué tienen esas variables. Si miras más atrás en el código vemos:

```
numero=np.array([2,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,4,6,3])
repeticiones={}
```

Es decir, `numero` es un array de numpy, mientras que `repeticiones` es un diccionario. En general **no se pueden comparar datos de diferente tipo**, salvo excepciones puntuales (como un entero con un flotante, pues en ese caso para hacer la comparación python convierte ambos a flotante).

No sólo es que la comparación esté mal por tener distinto tipo, es que además ¿qué significado podría tener esa comparación? Dicha comparación se halla dentro de un bucle, por lo que parece que lo que intentas es comparar *cada número* de la lista con la variable `repeticiones`. Esto seguiría estando mal, porque compararías un número (como 2, 4, etc.) con un diccionario. Siguen siendo diferentes tipos, pero al menos estaríamos un poco más cerca de la solución.

Vamos por tanto a arreglar el bucle. Tienes lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(0,9):
```

eso lo que hará será repetir todo el bucle 9 veces, y en cada repetición la `i` irá tomando los valores `0, 1, 2, ...` hasta `9`. No parece muy útil porque luego no usas la `i` para nada. Y en todo caso la variable `numero` sigue siendo el array completo, y no cada uno de los números que hay en él. Una forma más cercana a lo que (creo que) intentas hacer sería la que se ejemplifica aquí:

```
numeros = np.array([2,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,4,6,3])  # OBserva el plural, numeros
repeticiones =  {}
for numero in numeros:  # Fijate en esto
    print(numero)
```

Fijate que he llamado al array `numeros` en plural. Los nombres son importantes pues hacen el código más fácil de leer.

Después en el bucle, en vez de iterar por `range()` itero directamente por `numeros`. Así en vez de obtener índices (0, 1, 2...) obtengo directamente los números (2, 2, 4, 2, 5, ...)

Lo siguiente sería mirar a ver si cada uno de esos numeros (que en cada iteración del bucle están en la variable `numero`) han sido ya añadidos al diccionario, o todavía no lo han sido. Pero eso no se hace con `numero == repeticiones`. Eso no mira si el número **está** en el diccionario, sino que mira **si el número es igual al diccionario** (y no puede serlo porque son de diferentes tipos como ya se ha dicho).

Para mirar si un dato está en un diccionario (más concretamente entre las claves de un diccionario) se usa el operador `in`. Por tanto sería:

```
if numero in repetidos:`
```

Lo siguiente que intentas hacer es que si el número está en el diccionario, entonces hay que incrementar su contador de repeticiones. Para ello pones `repeticiones += 1`. Pero de nuevo está mal. `repeticiones` no es el contador que pretendes incrementar, sino que es el diccionario entero. No se puede incrementar un diccionario "completo", sino sólo uno de sus elementos. En concreto, el elemento que pretendes incrementar es `repeticiones[numero]`.

El diccionario es una estructura con una pinta como esta, por ejemplo:

```
ejemplo = {
   2: 3,
   4: 1,
   8: 2
}
```

en este ejemplo, `2`, `4` y `8` serían las "claves". De modo que `2 in ejemplo` dará `True`, porque la clave `2` efectivamente aparece. En cambio `3 in ejemplo` dará `False` porque `3` no es una clave en ese diccionario. Por otro lado `ejemplo[2]` te permite acceder al valor asociado con la clave 2, que en este ejemplo es 3. Así que si quisiera incrementar ese 3, haría `ejemplo[2] += 1`. La clave 2 me permite acceder al 3 e incrementarlo, y así pasaría a valer 4.

Esa es la idea. En este diccionario cada clave es un número que hayas visto antes en la lista de números, y cada valor es cuántas veces lo has visto de momento.

Una vez tenemos esto claro, sigamos. Tienes un:

```
else:
    repeticiones = 1
```

Aunque esto es sintácticamente correcto, no hará lo que esperas. No está poniendo a 1 el contador de repeticiones de `numero`, sino que está poniendo a 1 la variable `repeticiones`, que entonces dejará ya de ser un diccionario y pasará a ser un entero, con lo que en la siguiente iteración del bucle nada funcionará correctamente. Para poner un 1 en el contador del `numero` tienes que acceder a su clave, es decir:  `repeticiones[numero] = 1`

Vamos a eliminar de momento el resto de tu programa y quedarnos con lo que hay hasta aquí. Si ejecutas el programa corregido, cuando termine, el diccionario tendrá una cuenta de cuántas veces ha aparecido en la lista cada número. En concreto en tu ejemplo tendrá:

```
print(repeticiones)

---

{2: 5, 
 4: 2, 
 5: 1, 
 1: 1, 
 6: 1, 
 3: 1}
```

Lo que significa que el 2 salió 5 veces, el 4 salió 2, y todos los demás sólo 1.

### Paso final

Ahora, para cumplir el enunciado y sacar qué número se repite más de 3 veces, debemos recorrer ese diccionario, y si el **valor** es mayor de 3, mostrar la correspondiente **clave**.

El siguiente bucle itera por todas las parejas de clave-valor:

```
for clave, valor in repeticiones.items():
   print("El numero", clave, "apareció", valor, "veces")
```

Prueba a ejecutar este bucle y verás cómo funciona.

Te dejo entonces como ejercicio que modifiques ese bucle para que en vez de imprimir todos los contadores, imprima sólo los números que hayan aparecido más de tres veces.

Naturalmente, no es como lo tenías en tu código. Es más, la indentación en tu código también era incorrecta porque, al estar indentado el segundo bucle `for`, estaría *dentro* del primero y por tanto, por cada iteración del primero se ejecuta el segundo. Lo que quieres es que el segundo se ejecute cuando el primero *haya finalizado* y por tanto no debe ir indentado.

Answer (score 3):

El error está en que estás usando repeticiones como si fuera un número y es en realidad un diccionario

```
import numpy as np
numero=np.array([2,2,4,2,5,2,2,1,4,6,3])
repeticiones={}
for i in range(0,9):
    if numero in repeticiones: # se revisa si existe el key en el diccionario
        repeticiones[i] +=1 # se le suma 1 al key
    else:
        repeticiones[i] = 1 # si no existe se agrega el key al diccionario
    for j, r in repeticiones: #j es la clave, r es el número de veces que se repite la clave
        if r >=3:
            print("el numero " + str(j) + " ya se repitió " + str(r) + "veces" )
```

Comment: ohhh gracias ya entendí pero al ejecutar el código me aparece este error unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'